# Highmaps - how to draw two mabBubble series on one chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to create a highmaps chart that contains two mapbubble series so that it will show two bubbles in each country rather than just one. I am however struggling to understand how I can manipulate the x coordinates of the series so that they are not drawn on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate second serie's data and change x/y values, because points are printed according to these values.